# Database (SDF) returning less than actual max rows

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-ce

The issue that I am having is that I have 12 rows in my SQL Server Compact database (`.sdf`).

However, when pulling the data to my list of custom objects, it only contains the first three objects from the database.

Is there a specific or even vague reason why I am not getting the full return of rows from my database? During debugging, it looks as if `maxRows` is also saying the database only has three rows.

Also, when trying to increase `maxRows` by 1 in code, an error returns that the database does not contain more than three rows.

I have tried this, repairing the database, rebuilding the database. The only route I have not taken is creating a brand new project, with a brand new database.

*Edit*

For clarification, this is a windows form project, and I am sending the `Recipe.Name` to a combobox on my form.

Here is my code:

```
namespace Recipes2
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private DatabaseConnection objConnect;

    private string conString;

    private DataSet ds;

    private DataRow dRow;

    private int maxRows;

    private static int Inc;

    private List<Recipe> myRecipes = new List<Recipe>();

    public Form1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.objConnect = new DatabaseConnection();
            this.conString = Properties.Settings.Default.RecipeConnectionString;

            this.objConnect.connection_string = this.conString;
            this.objConnect.Sql = Properties.Settings.Default.SQL;

            this.ds = this.objConnect.GetConnection;

            this.maxRows = this.ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

            while (Inc != this.maxRows)
            {
                this.NavigateRecords();

                Inc++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }

        foreach (Recipe rec in this.myRecipes)
        {
            this.comboBoxLevelSelect.Items.Add(rec.Name);
        }
    }

    private void NavigateRecords()
    {
        this.dRow = this.ds.Tables[0].Rows[Inc];

        string le = this.dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();
        string na = this.dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
        string ing = this.dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
        string ef = this.dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString();
        string ob = this.dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(4).ToString();

        this.myRecipes.Add(
            new Recipe(le, na, ing, ef, ob));
    }

    public class Recipe
    {
        public string Level { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Ingredients { get; set; }

        public string Effects { get; set; }

        public string Obtain { get; set; }

        public Recipe(string level, string name, 
        string ingredients, string effects, string obtain)
        {
            this.Level = level;

            this.Name = name;

            this.Ingredients = ingredients;

            this.Effects = effects;

            this.Obtain = obtain;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look in your bin/debug folder for a copy of the database file

Comment: That was the issue. I did not even think to look there! Thanks for your quick reply =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in your bin/debug folder, I think you will find a copy of your database file there with the expected data